# Handling servlet output in AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets, arraylist

My problem: I am sending a request to a servlet from an AJAX function in a JSP.

The servlet processes the data and returns a `ArrayList`.

My question is how to handle the `ArrayList` inside AJAX, and display it as a table in same JSP.

The code is

```
function ajaxFunction ( ) {

 // var url= codeid.options[codeid.selectedIndex].text;
 url="mstParts?caseNo=9&cdid=QCYST0020E1";
 //  alert(cid);
   var httpRequest;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  if (httpRequest == null){ alert('null');}

alert(url);
    httpRequest.open("GET", url, true );

   httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(httpRequest); };
  //httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    httpRequest.send(null);

  alert('t1');
}

function alertContents(httpRequest) {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
        var cType =httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
        //document.write(httpRequest.toString());
      // alert(cType);
       // var xmlDoc=httpRequest.responseText;
        //document.write(xmlDoc.toString());
      //  if (xmlDoc == null) {alert('null returned');}
        if (!httpRequest.status == 200) {
            alert('Request error. Http code: ' + httpRequest.status);
        }
        else
            {
                var profileXML = eval(<%=request.getAttribute("data")%>);
                if ( profileXML != null){ alert('null'); }//else { alert(profileXML(0)); }
               // httpRequest.getAttribute("data");


            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ```
> var profileXML = eval(<%=request.getAttribute("data")%>);
> ```

Firstly, I would recommend you to learn about the wall between JavaScript and JSP. JS runs entirely at the **client side** and JSP/Java runs entirely at the **server side**. They certainly doesn't run in sync as you seem to think. To learn more, read [this blog article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html).

> ```
> function ajaxFunction ( )
> ```

Secondly, I would recommend you to use an existing, robust, thoroughly-developed, well-maintained JavaScript library with Ajaxical capabilities such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) instead of reinventing the AJAX wheel and fighting/struggling/worrying with browser specific issues/troubles/behaviors/pains. I would also recommend to use [JSON](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)) as data transfer format between Java Servlet at server and JavaScript at client. In the Java side you can use the great [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for this.

Here's a kickoff example with all of the mentioned techniques. Let's start with a Servlet and a JavaBean:

```
public class JsonServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Data> list = dataDAO.list();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(list));
    }
}

public class Data {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer value;
    // Add/generate getters/setters.
}
```

The `JsonServlet` (you may name it whatever you want, this is just a basic example) should be mapped in `web.xml` on a known `url-pattern`, let's use `/json` in this example. The class `Data` just represents one row of your HTML table (and the database table).

Now, here's how you can load a table with help of [jQuery.getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON):

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/json", function(list) {
    var table = $('#tableid');
    $.each(list, function(index, data) {
        $('<tr>').appendTo(table)
            .append($('<td>').text(data.id))
            .append($('<td>').text(data.name))
            .append($('<td>').text(data.value));
    });
});
```

The `tableid` of course denotes the `id`of the `<table>` element in question.

That should be it. After all it's fairly simple, believe me. Good luck.

Comment: thanks Mr.BalusC , i appreciate it. i am just boxed into this project as no other alternatives available in my company :-) , basically i am having a long association with MS guys. so i find it little bit difficult to adopt , any way i will take this as a starter to learn .thanks once again.