# Need Json results in a Table Format

Tags: java, html, json, servlets

I am getting results in json format, i need to display my results in a table format, Getting a input from html, executing it servlet program, the sparql query shows result in Json format, can anybody help me in showing the result in table format?

```
response.setContentType("json-comment-filtered");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","nocache");

OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
//  ResultSetFormatter.outputAsXML(out, results);
System.out.println("called");
out.flush();
JSONOutput jOut = new JSONOutput();
jOut.format(out, results);
```

soon the query is executed, the set of code is executed and results are displayed in json format, so can anybody help me out in way that I can get results in table format.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your Json? I'm assuming you are getting back an 'array' of objects?

Answer (score 9):

Your *actual* problem is that you don't know how to process the JSON string in the client side. I strongly suggest to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for this since this simplifies DOM manipulation a lot. I suggest to go through [their tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) or go get a [decent book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355) on the subject.

For the jQuery + JSON + Servlet + HTML table mix, I've posted similar answers before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203269/loading-alternative-content-via-tabs-and-jquery-and-jsp/2203376#2203376) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900711/handling-servlet-output-in-ajax/1900796#1900796) with code examples how to populate a table with help of [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and a Servlet, you may find it useful. I'll copypaste from one of them.

Here are the Servlet and the Javabean:

```
public class JsonServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Data> list = dataDAO.list();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(list));
    }
}

public class Data {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer value;
    // Add/generate getters/setters.
}
```

The `JsonServlet` (you may name it whatever you want, this is just a basic example) should be mapped in `web.xml` on a known `url-pattern`, let's use `/json` in this example. The class `Data` just represents one row of your HTML table (and the database table).

Now, here's how you can load a table with help of [jQuery.getJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900711/handling-servlet-output-in-ajax/1900796#1900796):

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/json", function(list) {
    var table = $('#tableid');
    $.each(list, function(index, data) {
        $('<tr>').appendTo(table)
            .append($('<td>').text(data.id))
            .append($('<td>').text(data.name))
            .append($('<td>').text(data.value));
    });
});
```

The `tableid` of course denotes the `id`of the HTML `<table>` element in question.

```
<table id="tableId"></table>
```

That should be it. After all it's fairly simple, believe me. Good luck.