# Render HTML table with JSF

Tags: jsf, servlets

I need to render an HTML table from a Servlet, in response to an AJAX request.  I'm wondering what the best way to go about this is?  I've explored using an javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable.  One of the questions I have regarding this method is how to render the HTML once the table has been populated.  From the looks of it, a FacesContext is required.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF isn't what you're looking for. It's a component based MVC framework. Just do it either the easy and ugly way in a simple loop in the servlet:

```
writer.write("<table>");
for (Item item : items) {
    writer.write("<tr>");
    writer.write(String.format("<td>%s</td>", item.getFoo()));
    writer.write(String.format("<td>%s</td>", item.getBar()));
    writer.write("</tr>");
}
writer.write("</table>");
```

Or store it as request attribute and forward to a JSP

```
request.setAttribute("items", items);
request.getRequestDispatcher("items.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Which in turn basically contains the following:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
        <tr>
            <tr>${item.foo}</td>
            <tr>${item.bar}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Or rather look for a different and more flexible data format like [JSON](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)) so that the client has the freedom how to render it. Here's an example which uses [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
writer.write(new Gson().toJson(items));
```

Which you can render into a table using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) as follows:

```
$.getJSON('json/items', function(items) {
    var table = $('#someelement').append('<table>');
    $(items).each(function(i, item) {
        var row = table.append('<tr>');
        row.append('<td>').text(item.foo);
        row.append('<td>').text(item.bar);
    });
});
```

#### See also:

- [What is the difference between JSP, Servlet and JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)
- [JSON from Servlet to HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758873/need-json-results-in-a-table-format/2759190#2759190)

Comment: Thanks BalusC.  I used a StringBuilder to do it.  Seems pretty light weight.

I actually got the HtmlDataTable idea from your blog.  --> http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#PopulateDynamicData